# Exclude scroll from touch events in javascript

Tags: javascript, swipe, touch-event

I am trying to make a swipeout list in javascript, something like Gmail app on android has. I am using events like `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend`. Everything works fine when I swipe a list item left or right, but when I try to scroll down through the list it moves the list item that my finger is on (because I don't drag my finger completely vertical when I scroll). Is there an easy way to solve this by differentiating swipe event from scroll event or something like that?

```
const SwipeOutList = function(listId, items) {
  const listElement = document.getElementById(listId);
  let touchStart = null;
  let movedTo = null;

  const findContentParent = function(element) {
    if(!element.parentNode) {
      return null;
    }
    if(element.className === 'content') {
      return element;
    } else {
      return findContentParent(element.parentNode);
    }
  };

  const fja = function(e) {
    movedTo = e.changedTouches[0].clientX;
    let contentElement;

    if(e.target.className === 'content') {
      contentElement = e.target;
    } else {
      contentElement = findContentParent(e.target);
    }

    console.log(contentElement);

    if(touchStart > movedTo) {
      contentElement.style.transform = `translate3d(${-Math.abs(touchStart - movedTo)}px, 0px, 0px)`;
    } else {
      contentElement.style.transform = `translate3d(${Math.abs(touchStart - movedTo)}px, 0px, 0px)`;
    }
  };

  const handleTouchEnd = function(e) {
    let contentElement = e.target;
    if(contentElement.className !== 'content') {
      contentElement = findContentParent(contentElement);
    }
    let a = parseInt(contentElement.style.transform.split('(')[1]);
    if(Math.abs(a) > contentElement.offsetWidth/2) {
      swipeOut(a, contentElement);
    } else {
      snapBack(a, contentElement);
    }
  };

  const snapBack = function(currentTransform, element) {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      if(currentTransform > 0) {
        element.style.transform = `translate3d(${currentTransform - 5}px, 0px, 0px)`;
        currentTransform -= 5;
      } else {
        element.style.transform = `translate3d(${currentTransform + 5}px, 0px, 0px)`;
        currentTransform += 5;
      }

      if(Math.abs(currentTransform) <= 5) {
        element.style.transform = `translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)`;
        clearInterval(interval);
      }

      if(currentTransform === 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 10);
  };

  const composeListItem = function(content) {
    let listItem = document.createElement('div');
    listItem.className = 'swipe-out-list-item';
    listItem.style.cssText = 'position: relative; height: 100px; transition: height .5s;';
    let contentElement = document.createElement('div');
    contentElement.className = 'content';
    contentElement.style.cssText = 'box-sizing: border-box; background-color: white; position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0; border-bottom: solid 1px blue; min-height: 2em; width: 100%; height: 100%;';
    if(content.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      contentElement.appendChild(content);
    } else {
      contentElement.innerText = content;
    }

    listItem.appendChild(contentElement);
    let backgroundElement = document.createElement('div');
    backgroundElement.className = 'background';
    backgroundElement.style.cssText = 'display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between; transition: all 0.5s; z-index: -1; background-color: red; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;';
    backgroundElement.innerHTML = `
      <div style="transition: all .5s;">trash</div>
      <div style="transition: all .5s;">trash</div>
    `;
    listItem.appendChild(backgroundElement);
    return listItem;
  };

  const swipeOut = function(currentTransform, element) {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      if(currentTransform > 0) {
        element.style.transform = `translate3d(${currentTransform + 5}px, 0px, 0px)`;
        currentTransform += 5;
      } else {
        element.style.transform = `translate3d(${currentTransform - 5}px, 0px, 0px)`;
        currentTransform -= 5;
      }

      if(Math.abs(currentTransform) >= element.offsetWidth + 20) {
        const parent = element.parentNode;
        parent.removeChild(element);
        parent.style.height = '0px';
        parent.children[0].children[0].style.opacity = 0;
        parent.children[0].children[1].style.opacity = 0;
        setTimeout(() => {
          parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
        }, 500);
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 5);
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    listElement.appendChild(composeListItem(items[i]));

  }

  let array2 = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

  for(let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    array2[i].addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
      touchStart = e.touches[0].clientX;
    })
    array2[i].addEventListener('touchmove', fja);
    array2[i].addEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd);
  }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all... just straight guessing because I never tried something like that.

Well, let's go please have a look at my included code =)

```js
// ------------ // 
// DOM ELEMENTS //
// ------------ // 
const div_moveArea = document.getElementById("moveArea");
const label_moveAxis = document.getElementById("moveAxis");

// ------- // 
// GLOBALS //
// ------- //
var lastMouseEvent = null;

// --------------- // 
// EVENT LISTENERS //
// --------------- // 

div_moveArea.addEventListener("mousemove", event => {
    if(!lastMouseEvent) {
        lastMouseEvent = event;
        return;
    }
    // Get the difference
    let difX = lastMouseEvent.clientX - event.clientX;
    let difY = lastMouseEvent.clientY - event.clientY;
    // Normalize them to a positive value
    if(difX < 0) difX *= -1;
    if(difY < 0) difY *= -1;
    // Get the direction 
    if(difX > difY) label_moveAxis.innerText = "Axis: Horizontal";
    else if(difX < difY) label_moveAxis.innerText = "Axis: Vertical";
    
    else {
        // Should be called if both are the same ... use prefered axis here
    }
    lastMouseEvent = event;
});
```

```css
#moveArea {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="moveArea">Move mouse over this</div>
    <label id="moveAxis">Axis: NONE</label>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** You may want to have a count that changes axis only if the same axis was returned a few times.

Have a nice day, Elias :)